# How to analyze survival data when there are no events in one of two groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, survival, cox-model, logrank-test

I am working with data from an intervention trial with the goal of assessing differences in survival between a control group (n=150) which received no treatment and an intervention group (n=150) which was given prophylactic treatment. Both groups were tested every two weeks for a total of 12 weeks (i.e., six observations per individual) for the outcome.

The issue is, there were only ten events in the control group and zero events in the treatment group. I know I can perform Kaplan-Meier analysis and test for significant between-group differences using the log-rank test, however, I was really hoping to be able to fit a Cox proportional hazards model so that I could 1.) control for potential confounders and 2.) report a hazard ratio.

Neither my thesis advisor nor I are very knowledgable on survival analysis, however, I was suggested to simulate an event in the treatment group at the last possible time point (as this would be most biologically plausible in terms of prophylaxis wearing off) so that I could go forth with fitting a cox PH model. However, from my understanding, a cox PH model still would not be appropriate in this context, as the hazard ratios between the groups are non-proportional. Any advice on how I can analyze/model survival data in this scenario would be very much appreciated!